# Get data output as a list from CDF

Tags: cdf-format

I want to get the data from a CDF, ideally in a list of probabilities and values. How do I do this?

I can plot the data but I can't see how to extract the raw data behind the plot. My pathetic attempt to extract the data failed.

```
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 50];
D = EmpiricalDistribution[data];
{DiscretePlot[PDF[D, x], {x, data}], 
DiscretePlot[CDF[D, x], {x, -4, 4, .01}]}
```

An attempt to get the numerical data from the CDF:

```
N[CDF[D]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use capital letters for your variables. For example, `D` is a reserved system variable. Replace with `d`. To get values,

```
Table[CDF[d, x], {x, -4, 4, .01}]
```

Worth looking at: [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/1783)